# AngularJS ng-model doesn't update when scope value changed in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In html :

```
<md-card-title-text ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
  <span ng-model="user.displayName" class="md-headline">userName</span>
  <span ng-model="user.email" class="md-subhead">user@abc.com</span>
</md-card-title-text>
```

In angularjs code:

```
angular.module('authApp')
  .controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.displayName = localStorage.username;
    $scope.user.email = localStorage.email;
    console.log($scope.user.displayName)
  });
```

The problem is that `ng-model` doesn't update when scope value changed in controller. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Use `ng-bind` instead of `ng-model` for `span`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - ng-model fails on <span>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528478/angularjs-ng-model-fails-on-span)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ng-bind for span: [AngularJS - ng-model fails on <span>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528478/angularjs-ng-model-fails-on-span)

```
angular.module('authApp')
    .controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.user = {displayName : 'userName', email: 'user@abc.com'};
        $scope.user.displayName = localStorage.username;
        $scope.user.email = localStorage.email;
        console.log($scope.user.displayName)
});
```

Html:

```
<md-card-title-text ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
     <span ng-bind="user.displayName" class="md-headline"></span>
     <span ng-bind="user.email" class="md-subhead"></span>
</md-card-title-text>
```

or just `<span class="md-headline">{{user.displayName}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<md-card-title-text ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
   <span class="md-headline">{{user.displayName}}</span>
   <span class="md-subhead">{{user.email}}</span>
</md-card-title-text>
```

or

```
ng-bind-html="user.email"
```