# Anglularjs:how to show error array in span using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show error array in `span` using repeat. Can you please tell me what our best way to do it.

I create `span` and attached to existing structure. But I want to try this way. I am new to angular.

```
var errorArray = [];
                 errorArray.push("Test Showing multiple errors1");
                 errorArray.push("Test Showing multiple errors2");
                 //This will show all the colounms 
                 for (let key in error.data) {
                     if (error.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                         console.log(error.data[key]);
                         errorArray.push(error.data[key]);
                     }
                 }
                 vm.error = errorArray;
             });
```

#### HTML side Code

```
<span class="help-block" ng-model="vm.error" ng-repeat="data in vm.error">{{vm.error}}</span>
```

Comment: This has already been answered in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528478/angularjs-ng-model-fails-on-span

Comment: @rrd I saw that question but it doesn't say how to use ng-repeat with span. It's different issue.

Comment: Ahhh perhaps then, instead of showing {{vm.error}} you should show {{data}}

Comment: @rrd that worked, thank you

Comment: `ng-model` is meant for form control elements

Comment: To see how to make a `<span contenteditable>` element work with the `ng-model` directive, see [AngularJS `ngModelController` API Reference - Custom Control Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example).

Answer (score 0):

in ng-repeat you replace data with any element of `vm.error` array and  ng-model couldn't be in span tag.
try following:

```
<span class="help-block"  ng-repeat="data in vm.error">{{data}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

cause you are iterating on the data object.  so only thing available to your expressions would be data and not vm.error. Its like the value of i in for loops.

```
<span class="help-block"  ng-repeat="data in vm.error">{{data}}</span>
```